# Merge multiple Json strings with same ID

Tags: json, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a Json file that is structured like below[1], as you can see multiple keywords are attached to one newspaper article. I want to normalize the Json into a such a structure(DataFrame)[2]. Ive tried it with json_normalize but that didnt worked out as intended, also did some multiindexing but i cant save the results in csv formats and it makes everything more complex. What i want is to get the data in a structure to analyze it and label the whole article based on the extracted keywords as positive or negative.

```
    [2]
    ╔═══════════════╦════════════╦═══════════════╗
    ║ url           ║ date       ║ entities.name ║
    ║ http://ww.... ║ 2018-12-31 ║ 2018          ║
    ║ --------------║------------║ Bill Cosby    ║
    ║               ║            ║ Actress       ║
    ║               ║            ║ ...           ║
    ╚═══════════════╩════════════╩═══════════════╝  




 [1]
{'lang': 'ENGLISH',
        'date': '2018-12-31T23:46:18Z',
     'url': 'http://www.newschannel6now.com/2018/12/31/cosby-kanye-box-office-diversity-biggest-entertainment-stories/',
     'entities': [{'avgSalience': 1,
       'wikipediaEntry': '2018',
       'type': 'DATE',
       'numMentions': 4,
       'name': '2018',
       'nameNorm': '2018'},
      {'wikipediaEntry': 'Actor',
       'type': 'COMMON',
       'numMentions': 4,
       'avgSalience': 0.72,
       'nameNorm': 'actres',
       'name': 'Actress'},
      {'wikipediaEntry': 'Bill Cosby',
       'type': 'PROPER',
       'numMentions': 2,
       'avgSalience': 0.57,
       'nameNorm': 'bill cosby',
       'name': 'Bill Cosby'},
    {'name': 'music superstar',
       'nameNorm': 'music superstar',
       'avgSalience': 0.02,
       'type': 'COMMON',
       'numMentions': 1}]}
```

## EDIT

I managed by using group by and joining the values into one single column:

```
df.groupby(['url','date'], as_index=False).agg({
    'name': lambda x: ', '.join(x),
    'numMentions': lambda x: ', '.join(map(str,x)),
    'avgSalience':lambda x: ', '.join(map(str,x))
})
```

Comment: @sammywemmy see [2] this my expected DataFrame output

Answer (score 1):

You can use [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
from pandas import json_normalize
json_normalize(data,'entities',['url','date']).filter(['url','date','name'])

              url                                           date           name
0   http://www.newschannel6now.com/2018/12/31/cosb...   2018-12-31T23:46:18Z    2018
1   http://www.newschannel6now.com/2018/12/31/cosb...   2018-12-31T23:46:18Z    Actress
2   http://www.newschannel6now.com/2018/12/31/cosb...   2018-12-31T23:46:18Z    Bill Cosby
3   http://www.newschannel6now.com/2018/12/31/cosb...   2018-12-31T23:46:18Z    music superstar
```

Here is another option. I am relying on a library called [nested_lookup](https://github.com/russellballestrini/nested-lookup) to pull the data:

```
from nested_lookup import nested_lookup

keys = ['url','date','name']

res = [nested_lookup(key,data) for key in keys]
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(ent) for ent in res],axis=1)
df = df.set_axis(['url','date', 'entities.name'],axis='columns')

df

     url                                                   date   entities.name
0   http://www.newschannel6now.com/2018/12/31/cosb...   2018-12-31T23:46:18Z    2018
1                    NaN                                      NaN   Actress
2                    NaN                                      NaN   Bill Cosby
3                    NaN                                      NaN   music superstar
```

Note how json_normalize associates every row with the url, while in the nested_lookup option, NaNs are propagated instead.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply but thats not what iam looking for, what i want is your second option without the NaN, i need the entities.name values being linked to one row in in the url column, as they are all key words extracted from the newspaper article.

Comment: u'll have to edit [2] to capture what u want and make it clearer, cos at the moment, it appears as if u want entities.name on individual rows. u probably want it to be ```2018, Actress, Bill Cosby, music superstar``` ?

Comment: Thats right, i am going to reformat it, thanks for letting me know.